# SimpleXMLElement gete element or convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have SimpleXMLElement and I neeed get content filed (content = 10) I tried

```
 $xml   = simplexml_load_string($summContent);
 $array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);
 $array = array($xml->getName() => $array);
```

but have xml  - false and array - false

```
$summContent = {SimpleXMLElement} [6]
id = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1-fR7MXmjsr0juPWsbpK9RSY_WVW_XK77-krsmEcmdc4/oxi7ruj/private/full/R14C2"
updated = "2016-07-26T10:49:49.902Z"
category = {SimpleXMLElement} [1]
title = "B14"
content = "10"
link = {array} [2]
```

I tried `$summContent->content`

```
result = {SimpleXMLElement} [2]
@attributes = {array} [1]
0 = "10"

$xml   = simplexml_load_string($summContent);
```

exception:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
```

How do I convert to an array?

**UPDATE**

I work with Spreadsheet google api and when I crated field for summ I nedd get this summ, after I get by coordinates I have xml with this summ but can not get this field, who knows how to convert this SimpleXMLElement

dump my SimpleXMLElement:

```
‌‌$summContent
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
'id' => 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1-fR7MXmjsr0juPWsbpK9RSY_WVW_XK77-krsmEcmdc4/ood4aof/private/full/R14C2',
'updated' => '2016-07-26T11:30:46.528Z',
'category' => 
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
 '@attributes' => 
array (
  'scheme' => 'http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006',
  'term' => 'http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell',
),
)),
'title' => 'B14',
'content' => '10',
'link' => 
array (
0 => 
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   '@attributes' => 
  array (
    'rel' => 'self',
    'type' => 'application/atom+xml',
    'href' => 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1-fR7MXmjsr0juPWsbpK9RSY_WVW_XK77-krsmEcmdc4/ood4aof/private/full/R14C2',
  ),
)),
1 => 
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   '@attributes' => 
  array (
    'rel' => 'edit',
    'type' => 'application/atom+xml',
    'href' => 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1-fR7MXmjsr0juPWsbpK9RSY_WVW_XK77-krsmEcmdc4/ood4aof/private/full/R14C2/lj40r',
  ),
)),
),
))
```

**UPDATE**

I get fiel content = 10 like this:

```
$arraySummContent = (array) $summContent;
$content = $arraySummContent['content'];
```

But I want know why to :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($summContent);
```

Comment: The error is in your $xml variable, you probably escaped all the tags, while they must remain untouched.

Comment: @RoboRobok I don't escaped tags, this is xml from google api spreads sheet. I also `        $summ = $cellFeed->getCell(14, 2);
        $summContent = $summ->getXml();` and I need field contant, thats all

Comment: Do this: `var_dump($xml);` and check out if they are for sure unescaped.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: First, remove (array) cast in your json_encode. You want to convert this object to JSON, not cast it to array before this.

Comment: @RoboRobok
in this step `$xml   = simplexml_load_string($summContent);` I have `$xml = false`  and in this step `$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);` have false too

Comment: If your $xml if false, then your XML string is invalid, like I said before. Can you paste full content of $summContent?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to access without seeing the actual XML (not the SimpleXML objects), but two tips: 1) You do not need to convert the XML to an array; just look at [the manual for how to use SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). 2) The output of `var_dump` is a bit misleading for SimpleXML, because of all the magic it does; if you want the string content of a tag, you should do `(string)$tag`. If you wrote `echo $summContent->content`, or `$content = (string)$summContent->content`, you'd probably see what you were hoping for.